# How do I scale maps appropriately for the grid for published adventures?

Tags: published-adventures, battle-map, roll20

I recently purchased my first add-on with Roll20 and noticed that while Roll20's grid is a 5-foot square, the provided maps are 10-foot squares.

How do I "scale" the map appropriately for the grid, and so that it's clear when something is 5 feet away vs. 10 feet?

Comment: Did Sdjz's answer, answer the question for you?  If yes, you could accept it.  If not, could you describe what it is lacking, and I might have a try at it.

Comment: @Kirt I want to say not entirely - but it's been a long time since I used Roll20 or had this issue. If you've got a working solutions, by all means post it. I do feel like the current other answer didn't do what I was hoping for, but it was quite a long time ago.

Answer (score 10):

### The page settings allow you to set grid size and scale

By accessing the options for each page, you can set the grid size and scale:

Access the page settings:

[image]

Then change the grid size:

[image]

If you have a map where roll20 is interpreting the 10 ft squares of the map as 5 ft, you can either increase the "1 grid cell" setting to 10 ft, making all squares get measured as 10 ft or if you prefer you can halve the "cell width" which will make roll20's grid smaller, with each square being 5ft in your map.